# Printing widget in GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt, printing

I've build my first gwt app and there is only one more thing I need to support - printing. I have a TabLayoutPanel and basically I want to print two CellList, one FlowLayoutPanel and a couple of Labels.

I found this open source project:

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-print-it/

What I tried was to create a separate FlowLayoutPanel (not shown on the screen) and add all the widgets to it one by one and call Print.it(...) on that widget. That didn't work. Then I've tried printing a single label just to make something work but no luck. I'm allways getting

**Error: Can't find printing frame.**

Now I'm looking at SO and seeing that this kind of printing is working for some folks. Am I doing something wrong? I will appreciate any ideas, though or comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Print.java](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-print-it/source/browse/trunk/src/br/com/freller/tool/client/Print.java), referenced from the [HowTo](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-print-it/wiki/Howto) project wiki page, you have to insert the following iframe into your page:

```
<iframe id="__printingFrame" style="width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
```